# number of vertices a special graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Suppose a tree G has exactly one vertex of degree i for each 2<=i<=m and all other vertices have degree 1. How many vertices does G have?

Comment: Try relating the number of vertices, the degrees and the number of edges using the Handshaking lemma.

Answer (score 0):

$1+2+3+.....+m-3+m-2+m+1=\frac{(m-2)(m-1)}{2}+m+1$

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this calculation is related to the graph problem? Does your answer answer the question?